# Swift-mailer send from different emails

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer, email

I'm trying to create a contact form, which the concept is that everyone can send an email with his own mail to my email, but when I use Swift-mailer, each time I receive the mail but with my email not with the email of the person who sent it..
this is the code that I'm using

```
if ($form->get('send')->isClicked()) {
    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject($form->get('subject')->getData())
        ->setFrom([$form->get('from')->getData() => $form->get('name')->getData()])
        ->setTo('myEmail@gmail.com')
        ->setBody($form->get('body')->getData());

        $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
}
```

Comment: If you mean that you want the email address entered by the user to appear as the address this email was sent from? That is a very bad idea, because that will increase the probability that those emails will be classified as spam massively. Don’t do that, use your own email address that this server is allowed to send emails for a sender address - and put the user’s email into Reply-To, that when you click “answer” in your mail client, the _response_ will automatically go to the correct address.

Comment: Yep, I added, ->setReplyTo($form->get('from')->getData()) and it works perfectly, Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the concept is that everyone can send an email with his own mail to my email

You mean that you want the email address entered by the user to appear as the address this email was sent from? That is a very bad idea, because that will increase the probability that those emails will be classified as spam massively. (Checking whether the server that tried to send a mail is “allowed” to send emails for that particular domain, is a large part of spam prevention these days.)

Don’t do that, use your own email address that this server is allowed to send emails for as the sender address - and put the user’s email into `Reply-To`, so that when you click “answer” in your mail client, the response will automatically go to the correct address.

Answer (score -1):

don't you have used this: https://symfony.com/doc/current/email/dev_environment.html ?
This is dev environment option to catch and redirect all emails

Comment: BUt using this option, u can control the "to" (the mail that ll receive) , BUt for me, I want to send from different mails that I can get from a given form to one mail

Comment: ok, I misread your post, sorry. Can you give us your swiftmailer configuration ?